# For loop skipping index in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote a for loop in JavaScript which is simple and straight forward. But, it is skipping the 2nd index. I don't understand why?

Below is my code snippet :

```
if($scope.usersChoice.length == $scope.correctAnswers.length){             
    for(var p=0;p<$scope.usersChoice.length;p++) {
        if($scope.usersChoice[p] == $scope.correctAnswers[p]){
            $scope.score++;
        }
    }
}
```

Here the length is 10.

Comment: can you show your arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you know it is skipping the 2nd index? Because it should'nt.
Can you show us your arrays ?

By the way, you can use forEach instead of for loop in this case, since you don't seem to need to break your loop:

```
if($scope.usersChoice.length == $scope.correctAnswers.length){  
    $scope.usersChoics.forEach($choice,$index=>{
        if($choice === $scope.correctAnswers[$index]) $scope.score++;
    });
}
```

Comment: I used debugger and found so. Here are my arrays :         usersChoice  : public static void main(String args[]),void returns no data type.,All of the above.,All of the above,True,both A and B,public static void main(String args[]),Both procedural and OOP are supported in Java.,synchronized,int[] []x[];


correctAnswers  : public static void main(String args[]),void returns no data type., All of the above.,All of the above,True,both A and B,public static void main(String args[]),Both procedural and OOP are supported in Java.,synchronized,int[] []x[];

Comment: Wait, you untitled your question "For loop skipping index in **JavaScript**
" but know you seem to speek about **Java**, there are differents languages and different concepts. Your comment is pretty cryptic too so, please tell me first how do you know your for loop is skiping one element ?

Comment: I used debugger statement after "$scope.score++;" this line. Then I found that variable p is not taking the value 2.

Comment: Perhaps beacause the conditionnal statement `if($choice === $scope.correctAnswers[$index])` is false at this index. 
Beacause your code snippet is perfectly right. 
Oh, and avoid use of `var`, in for loop you can use `let`, its scop is more appropriate.